# How to solve $(x-2)(x^2+1)^{1/2}>(x^2+2)$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I am very much tempted to square both sides to obtain a solution, but I'm not sure whether doing so is a valid step. What conditions should I impose on $x$ in order to square both sides?

In fact, this question leads me to the following problem: Under what conditions will $f(x)>g(x)$ imply $[f(x)]^2>[g(x)]^2$?

Comment: Note that $x^2+2\gt 0.$ So you can square both sides.

Answer (score 2):

To square and preserve the inequality, you need to be sure that both sides are greater than zero (where $f(x)=x^2$ is increasing).

This requires $x-2> 0\Rightarrow x> 2$. It should be clear the other terms are positive, and you do not need to worry about them. Good question!

Comment: for $x=2$ we get $$0>x^2+2$$? and then?

Comment: oops, strict will edit

Comment: @egreg I wrote greater but then used $\geq$ for the inequality

Comment: @qbert thanks for your reply. Does one miss a solution while squaring an inequality?

Comment: no, as long as you are working on one side of zero. Squaring is injective on each side of zero (so you dont lose solutions in an equality if you are on one side).

Comment: @ShreyAryan in general, for any equality, you lose solutions when you apply a non injective (horizontal line test fails or non increasing/decreasing) function.

Answer (score 1):

Note that $x^2+2>0$ and $\sqrt{x^2+1}>0$. Thus, in order the inequality is satisfied, you also need $x-2\ge0$: if $x<2$, the inequality is surely not satisfied.

Thus the inequality becomes a system of inequalities:
$$
\begin{cases}
x-2\ge0 \\[4px]
(x-2)^2(x^2+1)>(x^2+2)^2
\end{cases}
$$
The second inequality can be treated as usual:
$$
x^4-4x^3+4x^2+x^2-4x+4>x^4+4x^2+4
$$
or
$$
4x^3-x^2+4x<0
$$
This can be factored as
$$
x(4x^2-x+4)<0
$$
The quadratic factor has negative discriminant, so it's positive for every value of $x$. Hence the solution set is $x<0$, which, combined with $x\ge2$ tells us the inequality has no solution.

---

It would be very different if the inequality had been
$$
(x-2)\sqrt{x^2+1}<x^2+2
$$
Here, any value $x<2$ *is* a solution, because the left-hand side is negative and the right-hand side is positive.

For $x\ge2$, we can square and get
$$
\begin{cases}
x\ge2 \\[4px]
x(4x^2-x+4)>0
\end{cases}
$$
which has $x\ge2$ as solution set. Thus the inequality is satisfied for all values of $x$.

We already knew it, of course, but I wanted to emphasize the fact that just squaring would be wrong, because it would lead to $x(4x^2-x+4)>0$ and to the wrong conclusion that the inequality is only satisfied for $x>0$.

Answer (score 0):

it must be $$x>2$$ and we can square both sides and we get
$$(x-2)^2(x^2+1)>x^2+2$$ this is equivalent to
$$-4x^3+x^2-4x>0$$
can you proceed?
after factoring we have
$$x(-4x^2+x-4)>0$$ since we have $$x>2$$ you have to solve
$$-4x^2+x-4>0$$

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I just wanted to know whether one misses any solution while squaring an inequality.

Comment: i don't miss a solution since we have noted that is $$x>2$$ is hold

Answer (score 0):

The inequality is never verified.

In fact, for $x\le 2$ it is obvious since $x^2+2\gt 0$. Equalizing $$(x-2)\sqrt{x^2+1}=x^2+1\iff 4x^3-x^2+4x=0$$ and there is just one real root $x=0$ so never there is equality for $x\gt 2$ Since for $x=3$ one has LHS is not greater than RHS (one would have the absurde $\sqrt{10}\gt 10$), we finish.